# How I can test with jest the nested component of my component

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

How I can test the onPress with jest and enzyme my button component inside other component?

Exemplo of the code:

```
export default class PhoneVerificationScreen extends Component {
   render() {
      return (    
         <GradientButton onPress={this._checkNumber} />
      );
   }
}
```

Complete class: https://pastebin.com/ujN3hF0h

Comment: Spy on the function `_checkNumber`? Can you provide a more complete class component code example and what you've tried to test it thus far?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I update the question with the full class. Initially I want to test the onPress of my Component (GradientButton)

Comment: shallow(<PhoneVerificationScreen {props}>).find('GradientButton').props().onPress()